# How to use local conda environment over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, anaconda

I'm trying to run a model made using the fastai library on my home machine, but have to use my university facilities to run it. I have made a conda environment on my local machine with the required packages:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml #creates conda env called convml_tt
conda activate convml_tt
```

then connected to my uni and then their computing facility by ssh:

```
ssh username@remote-access.leeds.ac.uk
ssh username@arc3.leeds.ac.uk
```

However, when I have connected I can no longer find the conda environment I created locally-in fact conda is no longer found:

```
conda activate convml_tt
```

But I get the error:

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

(it is not installed on the university accounts). I am new to this, is there something I'm overlooking?

I have done all of this in the same terminal session, could that be part of the problem?

When I have connected to the facilities I should be able to activate the conda environment and run my model from there:

```
conda activate convml_tt
```

Comment: If conda is not installed on the university facilities, then you’re not going to be able to run it.   What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible to specify that the conda environment variable (and the environment) is on my local machine when I make the ssh connection?

Comment: If conda is not installed on the university facilities, then you’re not going to be able to run it. It would be like going into the post office and trying to buy a sandwich, or going into a gasoline station and asking for their Computer Science section — there’s nothing there. You say you “have to use my university facilities to run it”. Why do you believe that? Did somebody at the university tell you that? You should try asking them.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I'll talk to my supervisor today. Basically the model can't be run on my desktop, so I need to use the uni GPUs. I have a paperspace account and have successfully ran the model on one of their machines but my supervisor wants me to switch to the uni facilities to save cost and also get them cited if any publications come out of this.